# Delete large File with Filestream LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, blob, filestream

Deleting a file in LINQ with Filestreams is quite simple:

```
Table<File> f = dac.GetTable<File>();
var itemToDelete = f.Single(x => x.fileId == fileId);
f.DeleteOnSubmit(itemToDelete);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

The Problem arises when the File becomes quite large.

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait
>   operation timed out

My current solution is a workaround:

```
dataContext.CommandTimeout = 1000;
```

But I honestly don't like this solution. I don't have to fetch the Content which is the reason why the timeout happens in the first place.

Is there a nice and clean solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

this [Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx) provide a nice solution without even using a SqlQuery

```
// Create an entity to represent the Entity you wish to delete 
// Notice you don't need to know all the properties, in this 
// case just the ID will do. 
Category stub = new Category { ID = 4 }; 
// Now attach the category stub object to the "Categories" set. 
// This puts the Entity into the context in the unchanged state, 
// This is same state it would have had if you made the query 
ctx.AttachTo("Categories", stub); 
// Do the delete the category 
ctx.DeleteObject(stub); 
// Apply the delete to the database 
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I've got a Datacontext though when using this DataContext and attaching a dummyfile f: dac.GetTable<File>().Attach(f); table.DeleteOnSubmit(f); dac.SubmitChanges(); Again the Timeout happens. So it seems that attaching does query the DB.

Comment: don't attach file just create an object with the file id

Comment: You can't remove detached objects. Here the exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.

Answer (score 0):

I would just run the SQL strainght against the context, something like

```
dataContext.ExecuteStoreCommand('SQL TO DELETE BLOB')
```

Comment: As I said to Selman22, I was wondering if there is a LINQ solution to this too.